# ENOENT after publishing to Azure

Tags: angular, azure, npm, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm really hoping someone can shed some light on what is going on here.

I am publishing to Azure an Angular 7 / .Net Core 2 application.   I am using the provided Azure publish profile in Visual Studio.

The application works perfectly fine when I run it locally.  Upon deployment, I am seeing a string of error messages, mostly from npm regarding the package.json file.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors
>   occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the
>   Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: npm ERR!
>   Error: ENOENT, open
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\node_modules\start\package.json'
>
> npm ERR! { [Error: ENOENT, open
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\node_modules\start\package.json']
>
> npm ERR! errno: 34,
>
> npm ERR! code: 'ENOENT',
>
> npm ERR! path:
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\node_modules\start\package.json'
>   }
>
> npm ERR! You may report this log at:
>
> npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! or email it to:
>
> npm ERR!

[image: Example of the full stack]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by updating the ancient versions that Azure apparently uses to the latest versions of node that they support.

Here's the ancient versions they had by default:

[image: Default node Azure]

Comment: The above-given Image is the right one or that is the cause of the issue? the npm version should be 1.14.28 right ? which is mentioned in the image

Comment: how did you upgrade NPM version in azure?

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy all files under the dist/my-app directory to the directory wwwroot of Azure WebApp via Kudu console or FTP . A better approach is to use continuous deployment.

[image]

Comment: Put I'm publishing via Visual Studio 2019's deploy technology.   It builds, runs npm, copies everything.  I don't know what I'd have to do FTP, that is like going backwards.

Comment: Visual Code is what you need in that case, there is an extension to publish it directly https://dzone.com/articles/deploy-an-angular-app-from-visual-studio-code-to-a-1

Comment: Why would I need VS Code when I have Visual Studio 2019 Professional and all of the deployment technology is built-in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817745/deploying-an-angular-2-application-from-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821969/how-to-deploy-angular-6-app-on-azure-using-visual-studio-2017